# x86_64 gcc debug-mode: Why is there an extra instruction in add vs subtract?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I wrote the following snippet.

```
int Add(int x, int y) {
    return x+y;
}

int Subtract(int x, int y) {
    return x-y;
}

int main() {
    bool flag = false;
    int x=10,y=5,z;

    if (flag) {
        z = Add(x,y);
    }
    else {
        z = Subtract(x,y);
    }
}
```

but when I look at the assembly code generated, the function `Add` has one extra instruction.

```
0000000000000000 <_Z3Addii>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   7:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
   a:   8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
   d:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
  10:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
  12:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  13:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000014 <_Z8Subtractii>:
  14:   55                      push   %rbp
  15:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  18:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
  1b:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
  1e:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  21:   2b 45 f8                sub    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
  24:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  25:   c3                      retq
```

I feel a similar sequence of instructions (as those of `Subtract`) would have worked. What am I missing?

Comment: Comparing unoptimized code is an exercise in "why bother." Turn some `-O` flags on - I expect your concerns will vanish.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Well yes! and therefore I'd expect add to be optimized!

Comment: OK Sound good to me

Comment: The add function would be optimized to `leal (%rdi,%rsi), %eax \ retq` if you let the compiler do its job, which would then be an instruction less than the subtraction version

Comment: Because you compiled without optimization, the code is *not* optimized.  GCC and clang's default is `-O0`.  I'm a bit surprised that you didn't get a memory-source `add`, but obviously spilling the register args to memory is totally pointless and a huge deoptimization (which compilers do on purpose as part of `-O0`, for debugging.  See [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/53366394) for more details about `-O0`.

Comment: @harold yes! Thanks for this!